# Complex polygons with holes renders differently at each zoom level

Tags: here-api

We have a map application that is used to show counties in a state. In many cases local cities have their own jurisdictions, so when showing a county area we need to take the county shape and remove the cities that are separate.

We have been able to do this using the geocode function in the API to get the county shape and then grab the polygon for each city. From there we get the geometries and use pushInterior to create the cutouts.

On the whole, this works fairly well and even handles some pretty complicated overlapping areas. At a very close zoom we see the intricate borders perfectly, but when we zoom out the polygon starts to become unstable.

A clean cutout at the closest zoom, will begin to show random overlay shapes or connections as we zoom out. It almost looks like the polygon is adjusting to a lower resolution and eliminating some of the detail points to draw which results in large blobs or connections between points that fill in large areas based on random lines.

The odd part is that we have it drawing the shapes and lines. The lines are correct and follow the outlines of the shapes as intended but the lighter shape color is the part that is not displaying correctly.

Is there any way to force the precision or redraw of the polygon so the fill content is matching the outline?

Comment: What SDK or API are you using, please try to be precise on what exactly you are using or the answers wil be too broad.

Comment: As asked by Datasun, Could you please help us , which SDK or API you are using?

Comment: I am using the Javascript API 3.1.30.14

Comment: If there is an email or other method I can use to send you a private link I have a working example that shows the issue in action.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below code, which explains how we can draw polygon with Holes on the Map.

```js
/**
 * Adds a polygon to the map
 *
 * @param  {H.Map} map      A HERE Map instance within the application
 */
function addPolygonToMap(map) {
  var geoPolygon = new H.geo.Polygon(
    // define exterior shape
    new H.geo.LineString([52, 13, 100, 48, 2, 100, 48, 16, 100, 52, 13, 100]),
    [ // define interior geometries - holes
      new H.geo.LineString([48.5, 4.5, 0, 49.5, 8, 0, 48.5, 9, 0]),
      new H.geo.LineString([48.5, 15, 0, 50, 11, 0, 51, 13, 0])
    ]
  );
  map.addObject(
    new H.map.Polygon(geoPolygon, {
      style: {
        fillColor: '#FFFFCC',
        strokeColor: '#829',
        lineWidth: 8
      }
    })
  );
}

/**
 * Boilerplate map initialization code starts below:
 */

//Step 1: initialize communication with the platform
// In your own code, replace variable window.apikey with your own apikey
var platform = new H.service.Platform({
  apikey: window.apikey
});
var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();

//Step 2: initialize a map - this map is centered over Europe
var map = new H.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
  defaultLayers.vector.normal.map,{
  center: {lat:52, lng:5},
  zoom: 5,
  pixelRatio: window.devicePixelRatio || 1
});
// add a resize listener to make sure that the map occupies the whole container
window.addEventListener('resize', () => map.getViewPort().resize());

//Step 3: make the map interactive
// MapEvents enables the event system
// Behavior implements default interactions for pan/zoom (also on mobile touch environments)
var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map));

// Create the default UI components
var ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(map, defaultLayers);


// Add Polygon with holes to the map
addPolygonToMap(map);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    
    <title>Polygon with Holes on the Map</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-ui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="demo.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../template.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src='../test-credentials.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-service.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-mapevents.js"></script>
  <script>window.ENV_VARIABLE = 'developer.here.com'</script><script src='../iframeheight.js'></script></head>
  <body id="markers-on-the-map">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Polygon with Holes on the Map</h1>
        <p>Display a map highlighting a region or area</p>
    </div>
    <p>This example displays a polygon with two triangular holes in it covering part of Western Europe displayed on a moveable map.</p>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <h3>Code</h3>
    <p>A polygon is created using the <code>H.map.Polygon</code> class, passing in an 
      <code>H.geo.Polygon</code> holding the vertices for the outline and interior parts of the polygon. 
      The look-and-feel of the polygon can be altered by adding the <code>style</code> parameter</p>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='demo.js'></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

For more details please refer the below link.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/maps-js/geoshapes/polygon-with-holes-on-the-map